# Playing Audio from a URL source

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to play an audio file from a remote URL. The code works alright but the problem is when I tap on the play button, the app hangs for sometime before the audio plays. My code is shown below. How can I optimise this for a better experience.

```
                if(!isDraft)
                {
                    toPlay = URL+"/getFile/"+code+"_audioFile";
                }
                final Media mp = MediaManager.createMedia(toPlay, false);
                f.addComponent("Center", new MediaPlayer(mp));
                mp.play();
                f.getToolbar().setBackCommand("", ed -> {
                mp.pause();
                mp.cleanup();
                caseForm.showBack();
```

Comment: Probably the best, more difficult and strictly necessary optimizations are server-side. However, I have an app that is primarily video-based: it has issues with unstable/slow connections, that's why I added this RFE about preloading audio / video content: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2844

Comment: You are calling `play()`, `pause()` and `cleanup()` in a row. Which makes me think there's something missing from this code that's causing this delay. `Media` has a `prepare()` call that pre-fetches data when possible.

Comment: I call pause() and cleanup() on back button press...to dispose off the media? Is the prepare() called implicitly?